# Issue installing realm with firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to install Firebase for push notification and realm for database. It was working fine until i added Firebase pod to my project.

**Build Failed with below error**

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "__T09Alamofire11URLEncodingVAA17ParameterEncodingAAWP", referenced from: __T09App0A3ApiO4task4Moya4TaskOfg in App.o "__T09Alamofire12JSONEncodingVN", referenced from: __T09App0A3ApiO4task4Moya4TaskOfg in App.o "__T09Alamofire11URLEncodingVN", referenced from: __T09App0A3ApiO4task4Moya4TaskOfg in App.o "__T09Alamofire12JSONEncodingVAA17ParameterEncodingAAWP", referenced from: __T09App0A3ApiO4task4Moya4TaskOfg in App.o "__T09Alamofire11URLEncodingV7defaultACfgZ", referenced from: __T09App0A3ApiO4task4Moya4TaskOfg in App.o "__T09Alamofire12JSONEncodingV7defaultACfgZ", referenced from: __T09App0A3ApiO4task4Moya4TaskOfg in App.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

**Podfile**

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'App' do
use_frameworks!
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'RealmSwift’ 
pod 'Moya'

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = ‘4.0’
      end
  end
end
```

Comment: From what I can see, Firebase doesn't use Alamofire. Realm certainly doesn't. Where are the references to Alamofire coming from? Where do you expect Alamofire to be found, given there are no references to Alamofire in your Podfile?

Comment: Its used in Moya.

Comment: Where do you expect the Alamofire symbols to be defined? It’s not mentioned in your Podfile, so CocoaPods apparently isn’t providing it.

Comment: @bdash Sorry, I forgot to mention that pod in podfile. Its not actual podfile, just removed other pods. Appreciate if you can help me resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: How in the heck do you expect anyone to help you if you’re not sharing accurate information?! Update your question to reflect what you’re _actually_ doing, then maybe people will have a fighting chance at helping you.

Comment: @bdash : Updated

Answer (score 0):

It got resolved. Need to import Alamofire  wherever you are using the ParameterEncoding.

Answer (score -1):

**Replace your pod file from this code**

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Demo' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'RealmSwift’ 


end
```

[image: Please see the image]

Comment: Try building the project. It will give issues with Alamofire.

Comment: I did, it doesn't. Neither Firebase nor Realm use Alamofire.